# How to split string with delimiter and get the first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query where I have a table which is storing from information with a delimiter

SQL version - Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

```
DECLARE @commanTable TABLE
(
  CommaId NVARCHAR(MAX),
  Name NVARCHAR(500)
)

DECLARE @commanTable1 TABLE
(
   CommaId INT,
   Name NVARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @commanTable VALUES ('2324205.3933251.7336404', 'Test1'), 
('2324206.3933252.7336405', 'Test2')

INSERT INTO @commanTable1 (CommaId, Name)
SELECT  value, Name
FROM   @commanTable CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CommaId,'.');

SELECT * FROM @commanTable1
```

Getting the following results

[image]

Where I need the results to be

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, string_split does not guarantee order. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results#207293

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you only interested in the first value, you don't need to use `STRING_SPLIT()`. You can simply use `charindex()` to find the first delimiter and use `left()` to extract it

```
SELECT *, left(CommaId, charindex('.', CommaId) - 1)
FROM   @commanTable
```

---

Edit : if you always wanted the nth value, you can do a cascade charindex(). Provided that the n is not too huge. Else use the function that I provided in the comment.

```
SELECT  *, 
        item1 = left(CommaId, p1.p - 1),
        item2 = substring(CommaId, p1.p + 1, p2.p - p1.p - 1)
FROM    @commanTable t
        cross apply
        (
            select  p = charindex('.', CommaId)
        ) p1
        cross apply
        (
            select  p = charindex('.', CommaId, p1.p + 1)
        ) p2
```

Comment: Thanks present requirement is to get first value if I would like to get second or third how can I update it?

Comment: The issue with `STRING_SPLIT()` is that it does not return the sequence. You can use others like Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) or use a string parsing function like Peso's [fnParseString](https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76033)